# Why would enabling or disabling AdGuard for Android change my public IP?

Tags: mobile-data, vpn, ip-address

Since I just set up a VPN to my home server, I performed various tests and I found that, when I'm on cellular data, enabling or disabling AdGuard for Android (paid version) changes the IP detected by whatismyip.com or ipleak.net.

Since I'm on mobile, neither one obviously matches my home IP.

Today with AdGuard, for example, I could get 77.63.3.x which belongs to KPN, my provider, and an IPv6 address as well. Without AdGuard my IP is 77.63.6.x, again from KPN, but located in Utrecht.

Another day the difference was "bigger", not even the first byte of the IPv4 matched.

AdGuard is set to use a local VPN, since my Android is not rooted.

Comment: Does either of those addresses at least match what your mobile carrier would use? What do online WHOIS lookups report about both addresses?

Comment: A VPN works by routing all your traffic through the VPN service before it connects to the rest of the internet. As an example, one might live in Denmark, connect to a VPN, and to the outside world, your IP could be from a server in Japan.

Comment: @user1686 Added the info. All addresses belong to the mobile carrier I use.

Comment: Hmm, especially when it comes to mobile carriers, I really don't trust the third-party geolocation DBs – the same address might be used in Utrecht one week, Rotterdam the other week, if KPN so decides… (and similarly regarding 'first byte', address allocation in IPv4 is so fragmented that a single carrier might have [dozens](https://bgp.tools/as/1136#prefixes) of seemingly-unrelated prefixes.) So if both addresses belong to your carrier, I'm tempted to say that's just how AdGuard works, specifically the "pseudo VPN" mechanism that it has to use on non-rooted devices.

Comment: (That is, it has to intercept the TCP connections without any help from the OS, and make new connections and proxy the data through...) Without knowing how KPN works, I can't rule out the possibility that it doesn't assign addresses to individual customers at all, but only has a large NAT pool where each _connection_ can potentially get a different address. Do you get the same IP address if you check through different mobile browsers (e.g. Firefox vs not-Firefox)?

Comment: Same IP with different browsers, but I understand it may not matter after all.